# Getting closure-util : Permission denied on npm install

Tags: closures, openlayers, npm-install, permission-denied

I have a Openlayers package installed in my server and running npm install

but i get

```
> closure-util update

sh: 1: closure-util: Permission denied
```

I have done proxy settings as

```
npm config set registry http://registry.npmjs.org/
npm config set https-proxy https://proxy.companyName.com:port
```

But still getting same issue

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are using the `openlayers` package, which is deprecated. Try `npm install ol` to use the `ol` package instead.

Comment: On running npm install ol - it ended as `-- ol@5.3.3  extraneous`. And running npm install after this gives the same closure -util: Permission denied error

Comment: So it looks like openlayers is a dependency of another package you are using? What does `npm ls openlayers` show?